# Using powermockito in my test case and for the coverage I was trying to use Clover

Tags: javascript, java, unit-testing, clover

I have being using powermockito in my test case and for the coverage I was trying to use clover But then Clover is not supporting for the coverage. What would be the reason? any references

Comment: [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/154825/can-clover-get-coverage-on-classes-where-byte-code-altered) is a minimal reference.

Comment: But then I tried using Clover it is not covering the code

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen found in [this article](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/154825/can-clover-get-coverage-on-classes-where-byte-code-altered) it is safe to use Clover with Mockito or PowerMock. In other words, code should instrument and compile correctly.

However, please keep in mind that when you use a mocking framework, you are not calling real classes, but their mocks or stubs.

It means, that you will see code coverage for normal classes (as Clover instrumented them and this instrumented code was indeed executed) but not for mocks (as they are artificial classes).

Cheers

Marek